# An uncountable set of reals in which any finite sum of elements is irrational - without choice

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I tried to prove the following: There exists a set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $|A|>\aleph_0$, and, for every $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in A$, $$x_1+\ldots+x_n \notin \mathbb{Q}$$

I found a solution using Zorn's lemma. I'm interested to know whether there exists a solution which doesn't apply the axiom of choice.

My solution: Apply Zorn's lemma to find a maximal element among subsets $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that any finite sum of elements from $A$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb{Q}$. Now, if the maximal $A$ was countable, then we could extend it to $A\cup \{r\}$, where $r\in \mathbb{R}$ is picked as follows: take $r\in \mathbb{R}$ which doesn't belong to the countable set of elements of the form $q-S$, where $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $S$ is a sum of finitely many elements of $A$.

Comment: My guess is you need _some_ form of choice, like dependent choice. I don't think any statement concerning some (reasonable) construction on the reals needs the entirety of AC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: You can take
$$ A=\biggl\{ \sum_{n=0}^\infty 10^{-n^2} f(n) \biggm| f \in \mathbb \{1,2\}^{\mathbb N} \biggr\}$$
This clearly has $2^{\aleph_0}$ elements. And the nonzero digit in the decimal expansions are ever further from each other, so for every *finite* sum of elements from the set, there will be increasingly long runs of $0$s in the decimal expansion of the sum ...

If we change the exponents in the scaling factor $10^{-n^2}$ to grow fast enough (something like $10^{-n!}$ should suffice), we can even make sure that all of the finite sums will be Liouville numbers and therefore *transcendental*.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much.